# how to remove resize in text area tag

Tags: html, css, textarea

how to remove unwanted css property in text area box

i am marked in screen shot it will understand clearly my question

in Screen shot text area box bottom right side 3 lines showing how to removed that

```css
textarea{
     margin: 0px ;
     -webkit-box-shadow: none ; 
      box-shadow: none  ; 
      border-color: transparent ;
      height: 38px ;
}
```

```html
<textarea  id="txtarqlmchat"></textarea>
```

[TextArea box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6KzQ.png)

Comment: this is not clear, please mention your problem clearly, and attach the code.

Comment: in text area box bottom right side 3 lines showing how to removed that

Comment: @kranti Put up the code used so that we can check.

Comment: I think that is something the browser adds to indicate that the text box can be resized. I don't know what you would want to disable that, I think it's probably a useful function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot you market the right bottom part which is use to resize the textarea if you want to stop resizing use this css

```css
textarea{
     margin: 0px ;
     -webkit-box-shadow: none ; 
      box-shadow: none  ; 
      border-color: transparent ;
      height: 38px ;
      border: 1px solid #000 ;
      resize: none ;
}
```

```html
<textarea  id="txtarqlmchat"></textarea>
```

Comment: in screen shot text area box bottom right side 3 lines showing how to removed that

Comment: yeah i already gave you the answer na use `resize:none;` property it will be removed

Answer (score 4):

Add style into css or inside style attribute of `textarea`

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```